# Populating HTML table rows with objects containing an array using Vue

Tags: data-binding, html-table, vue.js

I'm trying to populate rows in an HTML table using the Vue framework - the data is as seen below:

```
TeamRows: [
            { team: 'One', times: ['1', '2', '3'] },
            { team: 'Two', times: ['4', '5', '6'] },
            { team: 'Three', times: ['7', '8', '9'] }
          ]
```

I've tried following this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpRpeq), but with bad result - this is my HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="(row, rindex) in teamRows">
      <td>{{rindex}}</td>
         <template>
            <cell v-for="(value, vindex) in row" :value="value" :vindex="vindex" :rindex="rindex"></cell>
         </template>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<template id="template-cell">
   <td>{{ value }}</td>
</template>
```

And this is the Vue component:

```
Vue.component('cell', {
    template: '#template-cell',
    name: 'row-value',
    props: ['value', 'vindex', 'rindex']
});
```

I would like the `team` to go in the first column in a row and the `times` to follow along in as many columns as there are `times`. Hope someone with more Vue knowledge is able to help me out here. Cheers.

Comment: If you don't use a `cell` component here it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/81/ Looks like the issue arises only when you're trying to loop components - it throws an error `row is not defined during render`. I've never encountered this to be honest, maybe someone from Vue team can clarify this (@Linus Borg ?). Also you have strange `<template>` wrapper for whatever reason, I don't think it's needed.

Comment: Because it's an in DOM template, that whole section between template tags in the table will be yanked out of the table by most browsers before Vue even compiles the template (because it is invalid HTML). Then, Vue will compile the template and will try to iterate over row, which no longer exists.

Comment: @wostex That worked like a charm. I only used the `cell` and `<template>` due to that codepen. Yours is simpler and it actually works. Thanks a bunch! If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as solved if you'd like.

Comment: @BertEvans I don't get it. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/82/ there's an error. There's no `template` tag or whatever. In my own code I'm using nested `v-for` with components no problem for some reason (though I don't see a difference). What is actually broken in this code?

Comment: @wostex Check out this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63t082p2/83/). I removed Vue so you can see what the browser actually renders (you can inspect it). Notice `cell` is *moved*. Browsers are very picky about what they will allow inside certain HTML like tables. It is one of the reasons the `is` directive exists.

Comment: @wostex see also this [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats).

Comment: Here is the [original pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xrzyqQ?editors=1010) updated to work with the `cell` component.

Comment: Thank you @BertEvans I understand it now. Also we can wrap a table into a component, so it's run by Vue, as I noted in my updated answer. Turns out, I did not run into such errors because I'm using single page templates, so that in-DOM template is always blank and Vue can shine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the reason is you're using in-DOM template and browser moves unknown `cell` element above the `v-for`, and Vue can't access row value anymore: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

A solution without `cell` component, just with inline cell elements, works fine. Also, `template` wrapper is not needed in a table template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    teamRows: [
      { team: 'One', times: ['1', '2', '3'] },
      { team: 'Two', times: ['4', '5', '6'] },
      { team: 'Three', times: ['7', '8', '9'] }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr v-for="row in teamRows" :key="row.team">
       <td>{{ row.team }}</td>
       <td v-for="time in row.times">{{ time }}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also, as a result of a discussion, you can still use a component if you wrap your table into another component for example, so that browser don't interfere and Vue has a chance to render everything properly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    teamRows: [
      { team: 'One', times: ['1', '2', '3'] },
      { team: 'Two', times: ['4', '5', '6'] },
      { team: 'Three', times: ['7', '8', '9'] }
    ]
  }, 
  components: {
    'mytable': {
      template: `<table>
    <tbody>
     <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.team">
       <td>{{ row.team }}</td>
       <cell v-for="time in row.times" :value="time" :key="time"></cell>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`,
      props: ['rows'],
      components: {
        'cell': {
          template: `<td>{{ value }}</td>`,
          props: ['value'],
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <mytable :rows="teamRows"></mytable>
</div>
```

Comment: I commented above why the cell component breaks. You could also use `<td is="cell" ...></td>`.